# Works on IE but Chrome & Firefox not

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

My JavaScript:

```js
var bossId = $('#BossId');
var date = $('#divDate');
var headDate = $('#HeadShipDate');
var select = '-- Select --';

bossId.change(function () {
    if ( bossId.find(':selected').text() != select )
        date.show();
    else {
        date.hide();
        headDate.val('');
    }
});
```

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "BossId", null, "-- Select --",
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
)

<div id="divDate" class="form-group" style="display:none">
    @Html.EditorFor(
        model => model.HeadShipDate,
        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
    )
```

Per the title, this script works fine on Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome & Firefox. How can I Solve this?

Comment: Can you share the generated markup for your view instead, please? Also, what do you mean when you say it *doesn't* work in Chrome or Firefox? What behavior do you expect, and what behavior are you seeing instead?

Comment: Well, I just want that when I select a value in BossId (DropDownList) the div date appears, just it, as I said, it is working on I.E., but not in Chrome & Firefox. In Chrome & Firefox, when I select a value, nothing happens. Regards.

Comment: Please show the *generated* markup that is being delivered to Chrome and Firefox. If possible, link to a live example of the issue.

Comment: Lol, I think it's solved. I just change the variable name from bossId to $bossId, It was claiming: "Uncaught TypeError: bossId.change is not a function".. Anyway thanks for try to help me.